# webdriver doesn't start, says: "Exception has occurred: WebDriverException" then spews html code saying "...w3.org" and "Restricted site"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, exception, webdriver

When trying to initialize the webdriver for any of the three browsers edge, chrome, firefox, and before the program statement "get(", on the webdriver.edge() (for example) on the webdriver statement line the program stops and says: "Exception has occurred: WebDriverException", and spews out what looks like html code from a website, that starts as:
`<http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` 
`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`
`<head>`
`<title>Restricted Site</title>`, and
`"The Internet site you are trying to access is not categorized by company's security vendor"`, and
`"web security vendor, McAfee, utilizes a site categorization engine named TrustedSource"`

This intranet network uses proxies and has a firewall.
Before I ever specify a website to go, during the STARTUP of the webdriver I get this error message.  Why is this happening and how do I get around it to initialize the python selenium webdriver?

I tied all three browsers; deleted the get statement from the program; went to: Visual Studio Code/Menu:File/Preferences/Settings/Proxy Strict SSL, and unchecked box; Created User environmental variables "http_proxy" and "https_proxy" and set to known proxy.

Comment: Update the question with you code trials and the complete error stacktrace.